# With CSS image positioning and screen resolutions, how can I best position this picture?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have a mouseover effect that when a client hovers a flag, a picture above it comes with a little icon of their country and a message, "View this website in English", or "Regardez la website en francais" or whatever.

I have tried my **css position** using pixels as well as percents, and still, if you're using a 1280 or a 1900 screen resolution, the picture could be way off.  Here's what I want it to look like:

```
                                                 picture should be here
                                   flag 1 flag2 flag3 flag4 flag5 flag6
```

So when they hover over, the picture shows.  [Treemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447128/treemonkey) helped me get there earlier today, and now I just have to get the CSS down.  Currently, my CSS is this:

```
  .map{
  display:none;
  }
  a.flagbutton:hover .map{
  display:block;
  position:fixed;
  top:14%;
  right:20%;
  }
```

If anybody could make any recommendations as to what I can do to remedy this issue with different screen resolutions -- if it's possible -- I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Hey Jason me again, look at the css i gave from the earlier thread, that should do the trick. Just replace ".item" with "a.flagbutton" and ".pic" with ".map"

Comment: oh sorry, I re-read it again and I think I'm missing something. I couldn't understand where on the page you wanted to show the ".map"

Comment: You can also set a title tag on the flag images so small text appears on mouse over of the flag icons. It's another option instead of using an image with the message in it.

Comment: Okay Ege!  I appreciate it!  Again, being in ASP.NET, like I told Kyp, here's what a flag looks like in my code:          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server"
           CommandArgument="de" OnClick="RequestLanguageChange_Click" class="flagbutton">
        <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/flagde.png" tooltip="View this website in Französisch"/>
        <img class="map" src="images/flaghoverde.jpg" alt=""/>
        </asp:LinkButton>

Comment: Thanks Anagio -- I did what you told me to do.  Some people, I've noticed, their browsers don't pick up the alt, or title, or (in asp) the tooltip, and Ege and Treemonkey really helped me out with the pics earlier today.  So I'm all set to go, just wish I could make the pics be in one place in most normal screen resolutions.  I'm workin' on it!  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Hey man, I don't know about the asp but if the css you posted is working properly than we can put it whereever you want. I just need to ask if all the .map images are the same size. And is it important if the map were centered over the content?

Comment: Thank you for being so persistent and helpful, Ege.  The CSS is working!  As you can see by going to ussvision.com home page, all of my map-hover pictures are exactly 120 width x 40 height.  Depending on the screen resolution, they're slightly off, but I'm working on it (with your help).  Thank you again for being so patient and helpful!

Comment: Well, I would *prefer* the map is centered over the content, but I don't mean EXACTLY centered ... I mean, as long as it's above the array of flags somewhere, so they don't have to look to the other side of the monitor ..... you can see the example in action on my site ... ussvision ....  com (with only one dot).

Comment: Solved.  I just put an extra parent DIV and called it "mapholder" above the div holding the images.  Then I made my CSS like this:               .map{
display:none;
}
a.flagbutton:hover .map{
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:58%;
right:40px;

margin-top:0px;
}

Comment: Now, it positions perfectly on 800 x 600 up to 1900 resolutions ... it's all the same.  Tinkering around with the CSS, I learned a lot, too. Thanks again Ege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a container for all the fields and another for the flag links

```
<div class="top_container">

    <div class='map_cont'>map</div>

    <div class='flags_cont'>
        <a href="#" class='flagbutton'>flag 1</a>
        <a href="#" class='flagbutton'>flag 2</a>
        <a href="#" class='flagbutton'>flag 3</a>
        <a href="#" class='flagbutton'>flag 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Make the top container's margin set to auto so it keeps a distance on each side and then float both the 'map_cont' and the 'flags_cont' containers to the right so they appear on the right side of the screen.

```
.top_container { width:90%; margin:auto; }
.map_cont{ float:right; }
.flags_cont { clear:both; float:right }
a.flagbutton { margin-left:5px; }
```

Comment: Hi Kypros.  Thanks!  It was a good thought, but the flags ended up being vertical, and I have so many divs in there already.  Also, it's in asp.net, so here's what 1 flag w/ associated image looks like now:         <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server"
           CommandArgument="de" OnClick="RequestLanguageChange_Click" class="flagbutton">
        <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/flagde.png" tooltip="View this website in Französisch"/>
        <img class="map" src="images/flaghoverde.jpg" alt=""/>
        </asp:LinkButton>